# Creating a report file for a questionnaire kind of application

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, birt

We have an application where user answers number of questions on a number of pages. Consider an insurance application for example. Users are asked about personal details, health conditions etc. These questions change on the fly depending on the previous details entered. We need a create a single html file at the end with all the info that the user entered. Now, what is the best strategy to create this html file? I can create a jsp file with custom tags that can show the data pulled from db. But we have two many conditional questions and it becomes a maintenance nightmare. Also, if I use eclipse BIRT or jasper reports, does it become easier?

One good thing about the requirement is, the interface on the final page should look exactly like the interface on questions page. So, one strategy we can use is to capture the html on each page with questions and user info entered, save it to db and retrieve on the final page.I was wondering if there are folks out there who use this strategy.

I welcome any other suggestions on how to do this. Thanks!

p.s. - I know it is really not a programming question but I'm just hoping to hear some suggestions.

Comment: I don't know alot about web pages, but having looked up "html file" it looks like only the file that the actual web page is stored on. That does not sound like a place to store data to report on.  Can you clarify where and how the data you would be reporting on would actualy be stored?

Comment: @JamesJenkins The first paragraph mentions that the data is pulled from a DB. The HTML file is the format of the final report.

Comment: So the data would be going from the web page to a SQL data base, then you would run a BIRT or Jasper report against the data base and return the results to the web page?

Answer (score 0):

XML plus XSLT is ideal for dynamically generating HTML. You could store the questions and answers directly as XML, or generate the XML from your DB (I haven't done this, but a quick Google showed many options for different configurations).

If you have an XML with a structure like

```
<questionList>
<question>
<identifier>1</identifier>
<questionText>What is your first name?</questionText>
<hasAnswer>true</hasAnswer>
<answer>Mary</answer>
</question>   
<question>
...
</question>
</questionList>
```

Then you can use

```
<xsl:for-each select="questionList/question">
<xsl:if test="hasAnswer=='true'">
<span> <xsl:value-of select="questionText"/></span>
<span> <xsl:value-of select="answer"/></span>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This will loop through all your questions and only display them if they have an answer. You could also skip using the "hasAnswer"-tag and only test whether "answer" is empty (by testing whether "answer" is not ' ', that is, an empty string), but I like the option above better. You can use the spans to add the same CSS you use in your question pages, or put everything in a table and use td's instead - it's very flexible.

In [the w3schools tutorial on XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp), you can read how to attach the XSLT style sheet to an XML file, which is as easy as adding CSS to HTML.

Naturally, I already use XSLT, and if you like your hammer every problem looks like a nail. But I'd really think this is an easy and light solution.